# parsing nested JSON in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, swift5

Can't figure out how to build the struct for this nested JSON.  I'm so close but missing something..

I'm trying to verify I'm loading correctly... the first two work great the nested data fails

```
print(json.pagination.items) // this works
print(json.releases[3].date_added) // this works 
print(json.releases[3].basicInformation?.year) //NOT WORKING, returns nil
```

here is the struct in built

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let pagination: MyResult
    let releases: [MyReleases]
}

struct MyResult: Codable {
    var page: Int
    var per_page: Int
    var items: Int
}

struct MyReleases: Codable {
    var date_added: String
    let basicInformation: BasicInformation?
}

struct BasicInformation: Codable {
    let title: String
    let year: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, year
    }
}
```

My JSON is

```
{
   "pagination":{
      "page":1,
      "pages":2,
      "per_page":50,
      "items":81,
      "urls":{
         "last":"https://api.discogs.com/users/douglasbrown/collection/folders/0/releases?page=2&per_page=50",
         "next":"https://api.discogs.com/users/douglasbrown/collection/folders/0/releases?page=2&per_page=50"
      }
   },
   "releases":[
      {
         "id":9393649,
         "instance_id":656332897,
         "date_added":"2021-03-28T10:54:09-07:00",
         "rating":2,
         "basic_information":{
            "id":9393649,
            "master_id":353625,
            "master_url":"https://api.discogs.com/masters/353625",
            "resource_url":"https://api.discogs.com/releases/9393649",
            "thumb":"",
            "cover_image":"",
            "title":"Ten Summoner's Tales",
            "year":2016
         }
     }
     ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm so close but missing something... :(

Comment: Change `basicInformation` property, of `MyReleases` struct, to `basic_information`.

Comment: Ah ha!  YAH... yes, that did the trick ;)  THANK YOU!  How did I miss that? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
json.releases[3].date_added
```

doesn't work with the given JSON, it will crash because there is only one `release`.

---

In `MyReleases` you have to add `CodingKeys` to map the snake_case name(s)

```
struct MyReleases: Codable {
    var dateAdded: String
    let basicInformation: BasicInformation?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case basicInformation = "basic_information", dateAdded = "date_added"
    }
}
```

or add the `.convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy.

You can even decode `dateAdded`  as `Date` with the `.iso8601` date decoding strategy.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i have a lot of JSON but I only shared the topmost as it contains the data I wanted.  

Thank you!  The enum thing confuses me but I'm learning.!! :) THANK YOU!

Comment: You need the enum only if the keys and struct members don't match. For example in `BasicInformation` it's redundant. And the naming convention encourages you to prefer `CodingKeys` over snake_case property names.

Comment: i get it...  As you figured, I'm new... just having fun! I truly appreciate your help...

I have one more problem..  basic info there is more nested data... arg... i will have to figure this out... 

"basic_information":{
//<other info> then this one.. 
            "artists":[
               {
                  "name":"Sting",
                  "anv":"",
                  "join":"",
                  "role":"",
                  "tracks":"",
                  "id":13961,
                  "resource_url":"https://api.discogs.com/artists/13961"
               }
            ]

Comment: It’s the same pattern like `releases`. Create a struct `Artist`, add the properties and appropriate types and insert `let artists : [Artist]`  in `BasicInformation`.

Comment: like tihs 

struct BasicInformation: Codable {
    let title: String
    let year: Int
    let artists : [Artist]
}

struct Artist: Codable {
    var name: String
}

?

Comment: how would I print / call this? it seems to be another array?

Comment: I got it.   print(json.releases[1].basic_information.artists[0].name).   it's a new array so starts at zero ;) cool... cool.. now I will put it on a table. ;) thank you so much!

Comment: Right, and you get it with `json.releases[3].basicInformation?.artists[0].name`. Use code    completion. Xcode shows you the available paths. And arrays (`[]`) must always be accessed by index. Once again, don’t use snake_case property names.